# How do i make my basemap line change direction

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am working on a flight animation. I have finally figured out how to animate a line so that it moves across the screen. I have no idea how to make it change direction even after researching and looking at matplotlib functions. Any Help? heres my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fig=plt.figure()

#map of Puerto Rico
bmap=Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=17.5,urcrnrlat=19.,llcrnrlon=-67.5, urcrnrlon=-65, epsg=4139)
bmap.arcgisimage(service='World_Shaded_Relief', xpixels = 2000)
plt.title("Flight Path of sbet 0059")

#generate the flight coordinates (just a straight line with 100 points)
N = 100
lon = np.linspace(-64, -68, N)
lat = np.linspace(17, 19.5, N)


    
x,y = bmap(lon, lat)

line, = bmap.plot(x[0], y[0], linewidth = 1, color = 'm')

def animate(i):
    line.set_data(x[:i],y[:i])  
    return line

anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=N, interval=N)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Well, it's not really "moving across the screen", it's just being revealed, slowly.  You can make the line be whatever you want just by changing the line's data in `animate`.  You happen to be pulling data bit by bit from x and y, but you could be generating a different line each time.  It's all based on the time, `i`.

Comment: Is this also you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446541/how-do-i-create-an-animated-polygon Like I said in that question, you make the line change direction by creating arrays of coordinates that change direction

Comment: No, me and her are working on the problem together though

Comment: Line will trace along what ever data you have stored in `x` and `y`. So you need to provide that data and it can go in any direction you want, along a sine wave, whatever. Are you asking how to compute the points along a different line? Are you asking how to concatenate two different arrays?